# .htaccess i want to deny access to all world but one ip for one page for ajax

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

here is the .htaccess

```
<Files login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

ip adress of my server is written in original one where 127.0.0.1 is.But all access denied to login.php ,i have ajax login form so it needs to reach login.php but it cant.please help :(((

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Satisfy any` like this:

```
<Files login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Satisfy any
</Files>
```

Comment: still same it denies all access

Comment: I have tested it again and it works fine. Is `login.php` correct filename?

Comment: yes it is correct all i can additionally is that i want to deny direct access to login.php but "login.html" has to connect login.php via ajax so all files is in the server with the ip 127.0.0.1(i changed it because i dont want to share my server's ip here so normally it is something different)

Comment: Can you check Firebug console and post the full URL which is getting forbidden error?

Comment: by the way it worked for php to php ,i just tried it,i mean like this 1.php to login.php it works like that

Comment: I don't know what you meant by `it worked for php to php ,i just tried it,i mean like this 1.php to login.php` Do you some other rewrite rules in .htaccess? If yes then post them by editing your question since they might be overriding this behavior.

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?